# How do I create an unreferenced copy of an object in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, object, actionscript, reference

I have an ArrayCollection full of custom objects.  I need to be able to create a copy of this Array, perform some functions and modifications to both the Array and objects within.  Then later I need to basically reset it back to the original stored copy from before I began.

The problem (and bug that I found and am trying to fix) is that I can't seem to create a copy of this array that doesn't directly reference the original.  ie: modificiations to the copy will also modify the original.

```
private var original:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
...

private function doStuff()
{
    var modified:ArrayCollection = original;
    for each (var myObj:CustomObject in modified)
        ...
}
```

The closest I've managed to get was using ObjectUtil.clone...

```
private var original:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
...

private function doStuff()
{
    var modified:ArrayCollection = ObjectUtil.clone(original);
    for each (var myObj:CustomObject in modified)
    {
        //Error here as the clone worked, however the objects in the array reverted to the base Object Class and couldn't be cast back to their actual CustomObject type
    }
}
```

Here's a working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var originals:ArrayCollection;
            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                originals = new ArrayCollection();
                for (var i:int = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    var myObj:CustomObject = new CustomObject();
                    originals.addItem(myObj);
                }
                doStuff();
            }

            private function doStuff():void
            {
                var modified:ArrayCollection = clone(originals);
                for (var i:int = 0; i < modified.length; i++)
                {
                    var myDupObj:CustomObject = modified[i] as CustomObject;
                    //do stuff
                    trace(myDupObj);
                }
            }

            private function clone(source:Object):*
            {
                var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                myBA.writeObject(source);
                myBA.position = 0;
                return(myBA.readObject());
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

And CustomObject.as

```
package
{
    public class CustomObject
    {
        public var a:String;
        public var b:String;
        public var c:String;

        public function CustomObject()
        {
            a = "Hello";
            b = "World";
            c = "Good-Bye";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I came to the conclusion that the various custom classes being used here are probably too complicated to be copied completely using a general utility.  They're also used in various other aspects of the application unrelated to the specific thing I'm trying to fix, so I can't really alter them to make them work a bit easier.

I ended up looping through the original arraycollection, creating new objects using the properties from the original...  ie:

```
        var modified:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        for each (var myObject:CustomObject in original)
        {
            var newObject:CustomObject= new CustomObject();
                                    //... setup properties
            modified.addItem(newLayer);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable to an object, is basically a pointer to that object.  So, when you do this:

```
var modified:ArrayCollection = original;
```

Original is a pointer to an ArrayCollection, and that pointer is now also stored in the modified variable.  But, they are still pointing to the same ArrayCollection.

You said you tried clone, but alluded to the fact that it didn't work--you didn't elaborate as to why it didn't work.

To copy, you can use [clone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#clone%28%29) or [copy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#copy%28%29) method in ObjectUtil.  I thought clone performed a deep copy, meaning that all objects referenced are also copied, but copy didn't duplicate referenced objects, so it is a "Shallow" copy.  I may have that reversed.

I use this method to copy an ArrayCollection in one project; which I believe is a modified version of the ObjectUtil.clone.

```
// clone method in ObjectUtils needs a UID; this one doesn't
public static function clone(source:Object):*
{
    var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    myBA.writeObject(source);
    myBA.position = 0;
    return(myBA.readObject());
}
```

Comment: The problem I had with clone as I mentioned in the comment there was that all the objects in the array reverted to the base object class and would throw a coersion exception when attempting to cast them to the proper object type.  I have seen and tried the function you posted as well with the same result.

Comment: I've also tried looping through the original array and cloning the individual objects...  ie: modified.addItem(clone(originals[i]) as CustomObject);  This results in an array of null objects.

Comment: CAn you provide a runnable sample?

Comment: Posted in the edited question above.

You'll note when debugging this that the originals ac will be full of CustomObject's while the modified ac will be just Object's.  The cast I have there when I loop through the modified ac causes myDupObj to become null.

Answer (score 0):

Change your doStuff() function as below:-

```
private function doStuff():void
        {
            var modified:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection()
                modified.addAll(ObjectUtil.copy(originals.list) as IList);

            //following code only for testing 
            for (var i:int = 0; i < modified.length; i++)
            {
                modified[i].a = "Bye";
                trace(modified[i].a);
                trace(originals[i].a);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This results in the same issue as before.  The ac is cloned/copied ok, however the CustomObject's within it are reverted back to base Object's.  Properties are intact (as before), however attempting to cast them back results in either null values or coersion exceptions

Comment: Add the following line in your doStuff method as the first line   registerClassAlias("CustomObjectAlias", CustomObject);                      This will allow your CustomObject class to be retained even after the ac clone/copy. Then you dont have to cast the object to CustomObject

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectUtil.clone(original)` approach will work if you add [RemoteClass] Metadata to your CustomObject Class.

```
package
{
    [RemoteClass]
    public class CustomObject
    {
        public var a:String;
        public var b:String;
        public var c:String;
    }
}
```

This should stop you running into casting errors when iterating the cloned collection. Keep in mind if your CustomObject has any properties of other 'Custom' types those classes will also need [RemoteClass].

Comment: I gave this a try, however ended up with an argument count mismatch. I didn't realize that was important when writing the example, but if you add a String argument to the constructor for CustomObject it ends with this error after adding the [RemoteClass]

Comment: Ah yes. I should have mentioned that. As in your example, a parameterless constructor is required with [RemoteClass].

Comment: ...or you can give the constructor arguments a default value.